# Best method for handling asynchronous USB data requests?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, winforms, asynchronous

I currently have a console application written in `Visual C# (2013)`. It opens up a connection to a `USB Multimeter` and then writes out the value to the console. I would now like to make this into a proper `WinForms` or `WPF` application (Data gets recieved, data gets sent to UI thread, data gets displayed in a table/graph etc). To do so, I need to receive the data on a seperate thread, as the data is sent through every 0.12ms (Which would lock up the UI on the main thread).

I have done some reading on both Threading and Async tasks, and as yet, have not decided which would be best suited to the task. Which of these (Or other methods) would be your method of choice for implementing this?

Please note, I am not asking people to write my code for me, I am simply asking which is the best method.

Comment: All you really need to use is the `Dispatcher` which will marshall the calls on another thread to the UI thread. You can run a `BackgroundWorker` which queries the USB port using the code you already have and just dispatch any updates to the UI. You could even just use a timer (`System.Threading.Timer`) that fires periodically, and use the dispatcher within that. The dispatcher will be on your WPF window/UC base class and it takes a callback which will be fired on the UI thread: e.g. `Dispatcher.Invoke(()=> { // code to update UI here });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asryael, your applications sounds fun. To beautify it you can create a WPF MVVM application.
It is not hard as it sounds.

Here is a basic tutorial:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial

**The basic idea:**

xaml -Defines the ui. Make it nice as you wish.

Then Have a variable in your xaml data bind to a property (variable)
update the variable in a thread everytime you get updates from your usb multimeter.

Have fun. Your application sounds like fun...